# JavaFX 2.0 + NetBeans + Maven

Tags: netbeans, maven, javafx-2

I am creating JavaFX **2.0** application using NetBeans 7.0.1. When I create project in standard way everything works fine. Unfortunately ;) I need **Maven** project...

I didn't find JavaFX 2.0 in Maven repository, so my pom.xml right now looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>mygroup</groupId>
    <artifactId>ui</artifactId>
    <version>0.1</version>
    <name>My Project</name>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javafx</groupId>
            <artifactId>jfxrt</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${env.JAVAFX_HOME}\lib\jfxrt.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

JAVAFX_HOME system variable is set:

```
C:\Users\rach>echo %JAVAFX_HOME%
C:\Program Files\Oracle\JavaFX Runtime 2.0\
```

Compilation goes okay, but when I start program under NetBeans I got error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/application/Application at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
```

However jfxrt.jar is in classpath:

```
C:\>echo %CLASSPATH%
C:\Program Files\Oracle\JavaFX Runtime 2.0\lib\jfxrt.jar
```

When I start my application from command line it works fine.

When I install jfxrt.jar in local repository at runtime application still does not start because it cannot find *C:\Program Files\Oracle\JavaFX Runtime 2.0\bin\mat.dll*. Pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javafx</groupId>
    <artifactId>jfxrt</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
    <type>jar</type>
</dependency>
```

Effect:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load library: C:\Repositories\MavenRepo\javafx\jfxrt\bin\mat.dll at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.startup(Unknown Source)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

Thank you for your help.

Those who are using JavaFX 2.0 SDK here are simple steps

1. Go to JavaFX 2.0 SDK\rt\lib in your shell (command prompt)
2. Execute mvn install:install-file -Dfile=jfxrt.jar -DgroupId=com.oracle -DartifactId=javafx -Dpackaging=jar -Dversion=2.0
3. Copy bin folder from your JavaFX 2.0 SDK\rt\ directory to your .m2\repository\com\oracle\javafx directory

4.`<dependency>

    <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
    <artifactId>javafx</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
   </dependency>`

Comment: My bin folder only contains one file: javafxpackager (mac). is this ok? should I copy it to ../javafx/ or to ../javafx/bin ??? Unfortunately, it does not work :-( Exception: Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ModuleVersionNotFoundException: Could not find group:com.oracle, module:javafx, version:2.0

Answer (score 3):

The best answer for current Java 7, with bundled Java FX 2.0, is:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
  <artifactId>javafx</artifactId>
  <version>2</version>
  <systemPath>${java.home}/lib/jfxrt.jar</systemPath>
  <scope>system</scope>
</dependency>
```

and add this to the "Run Project" Action of the used Maven profile in NetBeans:

```
exec.classpathScope=compile
```

You can also use this with the "Debug project", "Profile Project", "Run file via main()", "Debug file via main()", and  "Profile file via main()" actions :)

Answer (score 2):

For now, this seems to be a solution that works..

First, install the jfxrt.jar:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=jfxrt.jar -DgroupId=com.oracle -DartifactId=javafx-runtime -Dpackaging=jar -Dversion=2.0
```

Then copy the bin folder from your downloaded JavaFX runtime into your local Maven repo (home/.m2/repository/com/oracle/javafx-runtime/)

Not very elegant, but it works for me..