# Javafx project doesn't compile with maven

Tags: java, maven, javafx

I have a Java FX project and am using maven 3.0.5 to build. When i run mvn package/install, the project fails and complains that the package javafx.*** doesn't exist. Javafx is packaged in Java 1.7 to my understanding so it doesn't make sense that the build does not pick this up. When i compile it within my IDE (intellij) it works fine and after that my maven build also successfully installs, however i do not wish to have to go through the IDE every time i do a clean install. any ideas?

here is my pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>thenaglecode</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.thenaglecode</groupId>
        <version>1.0.0.Pre-Alpha</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>system-setup</artifactId>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-vfs2</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <includeEmptyDirs>true</includeEmptyDirs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.akathist.maven.plugins.launch4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>launch4j-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.5.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>launch4j</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <headerType>gui</headerType>
                            <jre>
                                <path>C:\Program Files\Java\jre7</path>
                                <minVersion>1.7.0</minVersion>
                                <initialHeapSize>128</initialHeapSize>
                                <maxHeapSize>1024</maxHeapSize>
                            </jre>
                            <jar>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.jar</jar>
                            <outfile>${project.build.directory}/systemsetup.exe</outfile>
                            <classPath>
                                <mainClass>com.thenaglecode.Start</mainClass>
                            </classPath>
                            <singleInstance>
                                <mutexName>thenaglecode-system-setup</mutexName>
                            </singleInstance>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

And here is my Log:

```
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /C:/Users/Macindows/IdeaProjects/thenaglecode/system-setup/src/main/java/com/thenaglecode/CommandHelper.java:[3,26] package javafx.application does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/Macindows/IdeaProjects/thenaglecode/system-setup/src/main/java/com/thenaglecode/ListAndOptionsController.java:[3,26] package javafx.beans.value does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/Macindows/IdeaProjects/thenaglecode/system-setup/src/main/java/com/thenaglecode/ListAndOptionsController.java:[4,26] package javafx.beans.value does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/Macindows/IdeaProjects/thenaglecode/system-setup/src/main/java/com/thenaglecode/ListAndOptionsController.java:[5,26] package javafx.collections does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/Macindows/IdeaProjects/thenaglecode/system-setup/src/main/java/com/thenaglecode/ListAndOptionsController.java:[6,20] package javafx.event does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/Macindows/IdeaProjects/thenaglecode/system-setup/src/main/java/com/thenaglecode/ListAndOptionsController.java:[7,20] package javafx.event does not exist
...
[ERROR] /C:/Users/Macindows/IdeaProjects/thenaglecode/system-setup/src/main/java/com/thenaglecode/Context.java:[3,28] package javafx.scene.control does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/Macindows/IdeaProjects/thenaglecode/system-setup/src/main/java/com/thenaglecode/ServiceMuncher.java:[3,31] package com.sun.istack.internal does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/Macindows/IdeaProjects/thenaglecode/system-setup/src/main/java/com/thenaglecode/TypeInfo.java:[3,31] package com.sun.istack.internal does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/Macindows/IdeaProjects/thenaglecode/system-setup/src/main/java/com/thenaglecode/NumericOnlyTextFieldChangeListener.java:[3,31] package com.sun.istack.internal does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/Macindows/IdeaProjects/thenaglecode/system-setup/src/main/java/com/thenaglecode/NumericOnlyTextFieldChangeListener.java:[4,26] package javafx.beans.value does not exist
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: It is annoying: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9294646/javafx-2-as-a-maven-dependency - works fine with JavaFX 8...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Maven project with JavaFX (with jar file in \`lib\`)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15278215/maven-project-with-javafx-with-jar-file-in-lib)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

placing this in the dependencies (depending on where your jdk is) will help the dependency compile, however you should probably replace it with a variable that the user can specify in their settings.xml or maven system properties:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaFX</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\jfxrt.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
```

see [Maven project with JavaFX (with jar file in `lib`)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15278215/maven-project-with-javafx-with-jar-file-in-lib) for more details as to why

Answer (score 6):

If you get these errors in a modular project with JavaFx version 17 using Maven, just try the usual things like standing on your head, walking on the ceiling, rotating the Earth in the opposite direction or even reading https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/ and then just switch to the version 17.0.1 or later and it should work:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
    <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
    <version>17.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Changing version from 17 to 17.0.1 worked form

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me.

Move sample.fxml to resources folder.
This requires changing your code to getResource("/sample.fxml").

Original answer: [Problem with JavaFX and maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53951676/problem-with-javafx-project-after-adding-maven-support-exception-in-application)