# JavaFX InvocationTargetError

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, javafx

At first JavaFX worked fine but when I added Maven to the project I had to reconfigure dependency and now it's giving me this stack trace :

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:473)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:372)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1051)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:973)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:198)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Location is required.
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3246)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3210)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3179)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3152)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3129)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3122)
    at sample.Main.start(Main.java:13)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:919)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$11(PlatformImpl.java:449)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$9(PlatformImpl.java:418)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:417)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:175)
    ... 1 more
Exception running application sample.Main
```

Here is my Main class :

```java
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root,
                400, 400));
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

sample.fxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextArea?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="400.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.Controller">
   <children>
      <Label layoutX="102.0" layoutY="26.0" prefHeight="39.0" prefWidth="182.0" text="Dictionary application" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="335.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="102.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="116.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="26.0">
         <font>
            <Font size="18.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <Label layoutX="224.0" layoutY="65.0" prefHeight="18.0" prefWidth="154.0" text="Made by Edita Komarova" />
      <TextField fx:id="definitionsfield" layoutX="35.0" layoutY="106.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="268.4" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="35.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="216.2" AnchorPane.topAnchor="106.0" />
      <TextArea fx:id="text" layoutX="93.0" layoutY="146.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
      <Button layoutX="206.0" layoutY="106.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleDefinitions" text="Get definition" />
      <Button layoutX="284.0" layoutY="361.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleHistory" text="History" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

I've tried:

```java
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/sample.fxml"));
```

But it didn't work.
Maybe it's a little different when you use maven with the project?
I would be thankful for your help

Comment: See the second duplicate; it should be more relevant to your situation. These may also be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53952139/6395627 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/59033005/6395627

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you use maven the fxml resources should be in a path like this:

src/main/resources/fxml/sample.fxml

Besides the .fxml file should rerefence the class controller.

`<VBox xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="SampleController">`

Comment: Is it suitable for Intellij? it's doesn't allow me to change from ```<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="400.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.Controller">``` Also is still gives me the same error.

Comment: Also added sample fxml file

Comment: Ok. you can use https://gluonhq.com/products/scene-builder/ to design/edit your UIs (fxml).

I suppose sample.fxml is in src/main/resources directory otherwise, move it there.

I don't know if the class sample.Controller exists, but if it doesn't then remove fx:controller="sample.Controller" and try again.