# How to tell maven that I need the javafx classes?

Tags: java, maven, javafx

That looks easy enough: search the net in which package they are, copy the dependency into your pom.xml and here you go!

But I didn't didn't anything that I could use as a dependency.

Not much of a surprise, other people had the same problem, and solutions can found here https://stackoverflow.com/a/29270114/4142984 in combination with https://stackoverflow.com/a/15692230/4142984 .

In other words, those solutions suggest to get the jar *manually* and **hard-link** it in you build-path. It worked, though.

But isn't maven supposed to do that?

Question is: what did I miss, to tell maven to do this.

And I'm using maven with eclipse, just in case this would make a difference.

Comment: Try rather this post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9294646/javafx-2-as-a-maven-dependency.

Comment: @davidxxx yes, it is.

Comment: JavaFX is part of the JDK. You don't need additional libraries. With Java9 you probably need a module-info to make it available

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yesno. It is part of the jre from oracle. Just in case you are using other jres you will need those classes in an extra package. And eclipse is IBM-driven.

Answer (score 0):

The links you provided suggest adding a JAR to your project CLASSPATH.  That's not using Maven.

If you want to have Maven manage that dependency, and it's not in a Maven Central repo, you need to do an `mvn install` to your enterprise or local Maven repository.

I'm not if [this](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.zenjava/javafx-maven-plugin) Maven plugin is what you need.  Maybe you can consider that as well.

Comment: I have to admit that, besides of copying dependencies, I don't have much experience with maven. Could you please explain a bit?

Comment: I have removed the jar from the eclipse build path and run mvn install. Errors are back, eclipse doesn't find the classes. I guess you are saying that I have to run mvn install with some arguments that are obvious to you, but not to me?

Comment: After some search, try & error, wouldn't maven at least need a dependency entry to the pom file to have a hint _what_ to install? And I really don't know how to say *jafafx* in a way maven will understand it. That was the reason for the question.